# stored prcoedure gives multiple resultsets instead of one resultset in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am using SQL Server and queries using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

I am calling a stored procedure in one of my database connections which gives multiple result sets.

By "result sets" I mean it gives multiple outputs like how we get two results sets if we query two select statements. The number of rows in the output does not matter.

This is a problem because if I query it in some another DB connection it gives only one result set which is expected. I am anticipating any DB settings for a stored procedure or something as a problem.

P.S. My procedure uses `UNION ALL`, stores everything in a temporary table and then gives the output of this temporary table.

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC] 
(
    @effDate DATE,
    @EffWeekDate DATE
) WITH recompile 
AS 
BEGIN 

    SET TRANSACTION isolation level READ uncommitted 

    EXEC pos..sp_nms_check_frag 
      @table_name = 'abc', 
      @execute_command = 1, 
      @include_investigation = 0, 
      @include_indexes = 0, 
      @include_statistics = 1; 

    EXEC pos..sp_nms_check_frag 
      @table_name = 'def', 
      @execute_command = 1, 
      @include_investigation = 0, 
      @include_indexes = 0, 
      @include_statistics = 1; 

    EXEC los..sp_nms_check_frag 
      @table_name = 'xyz', 
      @execute_command = 1, 
      @include_investigation = 0, 
      @include_indexes = 0, 
      @include_statistics = 1; 

    EXEC los..sp_nms_check_frag 
      @table_name = 'pqr', 
      @execute_command = 1, 
      @include_investigation = 0, 
      @include_indexes = 0, 
      @include_statistics = 1; ; 

    WITH tmp_hierachy 
    ( 
        column1, 
        column2, 
        column2_parent, 
        column3, 
        column4, 
        column5, 
        column6 
    ) 
    AS 
    ( 
        SELECT column2 'column1', 
        column2, 
        column2_parent, 
        a.column3, 
        a.column4, 
        a.column4 AS column5, 
        a.column6 
        FROM pos..abc A 
        WHERE a.rds_eff_dt = @effDate 
        AND a.column2 IN 
        ( 

            SELECT column2 
            FROM   los..xyz 
            WHERE  @EffWeekDate BETWEEN rds_start_dt AND    rds_end_dt 

            UNION ALL 

            SELECT column2 
            FROM   los..pqr 
            WHERE  @effDate BETWEEN rds_start_dt AND    rds_end_dt
        ) 
        AND    a.column2 != a.column2_parent 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT tmp.column1, 
        a.column2, 
        a.column2_parent, 
        a.column3, 
        a.column4, 
        tmp.column5 - 1, 
        a.column6 
        FROM       pos..abc A 
        INNER JOIN tmp_hierachy tmp 
        ON         a.rds_eff_dt = @effDate 
        AND        a.column3 = tmp.column3 
        AND        tmp.column2_parent = a.column2 
        AND        tmp.column5 >= 0 

    ) 

    SELECT * 
    INTO   #tmp_hierachy 
    FROM   tmp_hierachy 

    SELECT a.column3, 
    a.column1, 
    a.column2, 
    column2_parent, 
    column4, 
    column5 AS column5, 
    column6, 
    b.column7, 
    b.column8, 
    b.column9 
    FROM       #tmp_hierachy A 
    INNER JOIN pos..def B 
    ON         a.column2 = b.column2 
    AND        b.rds_eff_dt = @effDate 
    AND        EXISTS 
    ( 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM   
        ( 
            SELECT column2, 
            column3, 
            Max(column5) AS max_level 
            FROM #tmp_hierachy 
            GROUP BY column2, 
            column3
        ) AS grp_node 
        WHERE  grp_node.column2 = a.column2 
        AND    grp_node.column3 = a.column3 
        AND    grp_node.max_level = column5
    ) 
    ORDER BY column1, 
    column3, 
    column4, 
    column2_parent, 
    column2 OPTION (recompile)

END
```

Comment: So what is your question, how to retrieve multiple resultsets?

Comment: It will help a lot if you post the query inside the procedure and the result it's showing

Comment: No, my problem is multiple resultsets. It should give ONLY ONE resultSet like how it is working in all other database connections.

Comment: Voting to close as it is impossible to answer with the level of detail provided.

Comment: We need to see the proc or something that reproduces the behaviour.

Comment: Have added the procedure

Comment: `in one of my database connections` - sp body is different in that db then. Of the outer proc or `sp_nms_check_frag`.

Comment: This was correct @ivan starostin.  sp_nms_check_frag had an issue due to which it was showing 4 rows. It is now resolved.